# How to Keep Futon Running After Closing Mintty?

Tags: couchdb

Beginner question:

I'm using Mintty/Cygwin command line tool to start my CouchDB. I simply enter:
couchdb
... and that works fine. CouchDb starts and I can access Futon.

The issue is that when I close Mintty, I can no longer access Futon.

How do I keep CouchDB/Futon running after Mintty is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell bash (the shell running in mintty) to disown a running process with the `disown` command, which means that it will no longer pass on the terminal hangup signal (SIGHUP) when mintty is closed. Unless you've started `couchdb` in the background by sticking an `&` at the end of the command line, you first need to suspend it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then put it in the background with `bg`.

Or you can invoke the process via `nohup` or `setsid` (from the util-linux package) in the first place. `nohup` just blocks the hangup signal, whereas `setsid` starts the process in a background session completely disconnected from the terminal.